# Postgres poor performance "in-clause"

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-performance, in-clause

I have this query:

```
with serie as (
select to_char(kj, 'yyyymmdd')::numeric
from generate_series('2016-02-06 01:56:00','2016-02-06 23:57:00', '1 day'::interval) kj
              )
select col1,col2,col3
from foreign_table
where  col3 in (select * from serie) -- from CTE serie here is only one number 20160216
```

And its performance is poor, the foreign table has an index on col3.

But if I write the values from CTE serie manually it performs fast

```
select col1,col2,col3
from foreign_table
where  col3 in (20160216,20160217)
```

I put there one more value just to show it works fast with more than one value

And if I write "=" to first query instead of "in" it also performs fast

```
with serie as (
select to_char(kj, 'yyyymmdd')::numeric
from generate_series('2016-02-06 01:56:00','2016-02-06 23:57:00', '1 day'::interval) kj
              )
select col1,col2,col3
from foreign_table
where  col3 = (select * from serie) -- I can write "=" in this case because I have just one number returned from CTE
```

(I am using Postgres 9.5.1)

Why does Postgres performs so poorly with in-clase with CTE compare to manually writing these values or using "=". I obviously can not write values manually all the time since I need this query universal and I can not put there "=" because I need it universal here as well.

So any ideas here ?

btw: This is not the only case when in-clause made a poor performance compare to other two methods I showed here

These are the query plans, I have other queries that are not affected by foreign table, once I find them I will put them here as well

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6omIh.png

Comment: what is `col3`, an integer or a char field? Why don't you store dates as dates? Note: now I see you cast it to `numeric`. But why? BTW: is `from generate_series('2016-02-06 01:56:00','2016-02-06 23:57:00', '1 day'::interval) kj` supposed to yield exactly one timestamp?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info and add the missing information

Comment: to joop: col3 is a numeric, It is a foreign table I do not decied how it is stored, generate series gives my one number in this case because I gave it parametrs that returns just one value

Comment: If it really is a foreign table: why do you use a CTE instead of a JOIN (or even beter EXISTS) on a subquery? A CTE **has** to be executed exactly once, and its "value" is barely indexable. Combined with a *foreign* table (really?), there is very little room for improvement for the planner, IMHO.

Comment: but why are here those big differences in performance among those examples I showed ?

Comment: @Baker: could you please post your table definition and the query plan?

Comment: Please post the query plan as plain text (the output of `explain (analyze, verbose)` or upload the text to http://explain.depesz.com those screenshots don't show anything interesting

Comment: My guess is that the optimiser assumes to CTE to yield 1000 rows (the default). Which is wrong, of course. Adding a `LIMIT 1` to the CTE *could* work. But writing better SQL, and using the appropiate datatypes would probably work better. BTW: `where  col3 = (select * from serie)` assumes a **scalar** subquery. Which it is not. Apart from the `*` ...

Comment: I added limit 1 and named the column instead of using *, and it had no effect on performance nor on explain plan (it only added limit after function nothing more).